# Capturing oauthlib.oauth2.rfc6749.errors.CustomOAuth2Error when user is not assigned to a role for the application

Tags: python, django, nginx, azure-active-directory, gunicorn

I have a Django app running via Gunicorn and an Nginx proxy that uses Azure AD authentication (based on the following tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/python?tutorial-step=3).

At the moment when a user logs in to the app via Azure AD and isn't assigned to a role, Django shows a generic 500 error page. I want to display something a little more meaningful to the user, but I don't know where exactly I need to capture the oauthlib.oauth2.rfc6749.errors.CustomOAuth2Error and display it.

I can see the Django logs show: "oauthlib.oauth2.rfc6749.errors.CustomOAuth2Error (interaction_required) AADSTS50105: The signed in user '{EmailHidden}' is not assigned to a role for the application '[App ID]'(App Name).”

Would it be within the callback view that I have to check for this error somehow?
I was rather hoping Azure would show the error message by default, but that doesn't seem to the case.

Answer (score 1):

Refer this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-error-handling-python) for more details of error handling and exception handling in MSAL for Python. An easier approach would be to make the application to handle the *custom error message/ custom error display page* based on the error capture with in the application.